# renaming files inside zip while download on php

Tags: php

i have some question to tell , how can i download zip and rename the files inside the zip with some php codes ? here is my code :

```
$file_path='../../files_pangkat/';
$file_names[0] = $ck_sk_terakhir[file_pangkat];
$zip = new ZipArchive();

//create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
}

//add each files of $file_name array to archive
$zip->addFile($file_path.$file_names[0],$file_names[0]);
$zip->renameName($file_names[0], 'SK_PNS_'.$c_bio[nip_baru].'pdf');
echo $file_path.$file_names[0],$file_names[0]."<br />";
$zip->close();

//then send the headers to foce download the zip file 
header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");  
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
readfile("$archive_file_name");
unlink("$archive_file_name");
exit;
```

`$file_names` was the name of file that i saved on my database , but when i use `$zip->renameName()` , it doesn't work ..

Comment: "doesn't work" means what? An error, or unexpected behaviour? Please clarify

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to first add a file to the zip file and then rename the newly added file right after that.

Instead, you should add the file with the name you want it to have, also see the manual on [`addFile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php).

So you should change:

```
$zip->addFile($file_path.$file_names[0],$file_names[0]);
$zip->renameName($file_names[0], 'SK_PNS_'.$c_bio[nip_baru].'pdf');
```

to:

```
$zip->addFile($file_path . $file_names[0], 'SK_PNS_' . $c_bio[nip_baru] . 'pdf');
```

Comment: it worked when i try it with XAMPP , but when i try it with FileZilla , it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Zip creates a lock on the file..you cant rename on the fly ,close it and rename again.
Try it.

```
$zip->addFile('.....');
....
$zip->close();

$zip->renameName($file_names[0], 'SK_PNS_'.$c_bio[nip_baru].'pdf');
```